# Barcode Image in Java

Tags: java, barcode

How can I create a barcode image in Java? I need something that will allow me to enter a number and produce the corresponding barcode image. Remember that I don't want to use any of the free libraries available for this type of task. I just want to achieve it with a class file.

Comment: Any valid reason for writing your own code instead of using a library?

Comment: Well, if you *can't use* a library, then you will need to write it yourself (thank you, Captain Obvious!). The thing is: you need to ask a *more specific* question than "how do I do it"? Try to find the relevant standards for the kinds of bar codes you need, try to implement them and if you're stuck *at that point* ask a *specific question* about your problem.

Comment: i know i should do find the relevant standards for the kinds of bar codes i need, try to implement them and if i'm stuck at that point ask a specific question about the problem. but its like m no where to start at thought stackoverflow could gimme a start ... like some link or some tutorial forum something like that

Comment: Why should someone put out a tutorial on "how to create bar code images", when there are perfectly fine libraries that already do it? If *you* have the restriction of not being able to use those libraries (and you should *really* charge your customer extra for these kind of restrictions), then that's your problem.

Comment: being a startup company i need to agree with all demands of the client cant charge extra ... well i found something i need to create a barcode for standarad Code 128 ...

Comment: @Prashant: if you "found something" then that's pretty much a "free library", even if it's just code ...

Comment: @Joachim Sauer then please guide me how should i start with?

Comment: If you cant use a pre-existing library, are you sure your client would allow you to use a pre-existing stack, like Java? Me thinks your client is being unreasonable. I cant think of any reason not to use a pre-existing library, and without any such reason, the best advise it to use something like barbeque.

Answer (score 2):

Yes barbecue would be a good option. Its source code is available. I have personally tried it to make it usable as per my needs. You can see the code understand it and then write your own class for it.

Try out the following url:

[Barbecue Source Code](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.barbecue/barbecue/1.5-beta1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Barbecue](http://sourceforge.net/projects/barbecue/) framework. But, this is open source project.

Comment: The OP explicitly noted that he can't use any of the free libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Does your client have a problem with using a Code 128 **font**? I found a few freebies on the net, it was easier for me to work with a font than an image creator, plus it embedded into a PDF just fine for use on web based apps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you embed the barcode characters as images in base64?

`<img alt="104,{Start B}" title="104,{Start B}"
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AC3gAT0BDuLeG4IAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="30"><img alt=" 51,A:{S},B:{S}" title=" 51,A:{S},B:{S}" 
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ACLgAScBA3yI80wAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="30"><img alt=" 65,A:{SOH},B:{a}" title=" 65,A:{SOH},B:{a}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AGngAbUBSuiAnEkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="30"><img alt=" 77,A:{CR},B:{m}" title=" 77,A:{CR},B:{m}"
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AAigALMAqe/ygasAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="30"><img alt=" 80,A:{DLE},B:{p}" title=" 80,A:{DLE},B:{p}"
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AFhgARMAuXYaS+YAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="30"><img alt=" 76,A:{FF},B:{l}" title=" 76,A:{FF},B:{l}"
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADXgAU0BFkrGa3IAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="30"><img alt=" 69,A:{ENQ},B:{e}" title=" 69,A:{ENQ},B:{e}"
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AE3gAX0BLqHeudAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="30"><img alt=" 85,A:{NAK},B:{u}" title=" 85,A:{NAK},B:{u}"
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AGGgAWUBAqmuuv8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="30"><img alt="106,{Stop}" title="106,{Stop}"
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAABAQMAAAA/57ZEAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADigARMA2dpJzT8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="10" height="30">`

If so, the images are self contained and all you need is an array of strings. Sorry about the awkward formatting.